# Adding JSON samples with Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've used Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage and C# XML comments to generate Web API documentation for my Web API project, but would like to add JSON samples to each method, and can't figure out how.

Here's my method's XML comment:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets data values for a given data key.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="masterAgencyID">The MasterAgencyDivisionID for the desired values.</param>
        /// <param name="masterClientID">The MasterClientID for the desired values.</param>
        /// <param name="dataKeyCode">The DataKey's code for which values are to be returned.</param>
        /// <returns>An object containing two lists: IncludedValues and ExcludedValues.</returns>
        /// <example>
        /// {
        ///     "IncludedValues": [
        ///         {
        ///             "DataValueID": 644,
        ///             "DataValueCode": "1000X500",
        ///             "DataValueShortDescr": "1000X500",
        ///             "excluded": false
        ///         },
        ///         ...
        ///     ],
        ///     "ExcludedValues": [
        ///         {
        ///             "DataValueID": 644,
        ///             "DataValueCode": "1000X500",
        ///             "DataValueShortDescr": "1000X500",
        ///             "excluded": true
        ///         },
        ///         ...
        ///     ]   
        /// </example>
```

Here's the generated webpage for the method:
[image]

As you can see, under "Sample:", the page shows "Sample not available."

It obviously isn't reading from the  XML tag. What do I have to do to include an example in my API documentation?

Comment: I've not used the built-in API Documentation in Web API, but are you sure that's how it works? I thought it would have just created a generic JSON object given your object name/types. Can you link to the documentation that says using `<example></example>` in the XML comments yields this behavior? Could just be a misconception

Comment: I assume you compiled the documentation properly with `/doc`. To add code inside the `<example>` tag, you need to use the `<code>` tag. Here is the related [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/example).

Comment: @MarkC. : Yes, it could be, and that's the point of my post: I'm looking for anyone who knows *how* to populate the Sample:.

Comment: Hi @rothkko, have you figured this out? I´m trying to do exactly the same as you.